# NodeJS - Non-ascii strings. How to determine their encoding, how to extract characters and convert to ascii representation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, parsing, character-encoding

I am doing some web scraping with Node-JS and Puppeteer.

Some data is returned to me which looks like this:

```
{
    "priceValue": "£20,000"
}
```

This string is clearly not an ascii string because of the first character.

- How can I determine what encoding/representation, and character width, this string has?

I want to make a logic decision based on the first character. I want to extract the numerical value from this string and assign a `"priceCurrency": "GBP"` value to the returned object.

To do this, the most logical approach would be to take the first "character" and process it using an if statement.

- How can I extract the first character from this string and then compare it to some value as part of an if statement?
- How can I convert the remaining string contents to ascii?

Comment: ASCII encoding is technically obsolete, having been replaced by Unicode - so why do you insist upon ASCII?  BTW, when writing currency amounts, [the location of the symbol varies by language.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol).

Comment: @JosefZ I suppose it doesn't have to be ascii. As strings in JS ASCII by default or UTF-8?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant ... Regarding the provided answer ... (which also covers [_"How to process price / currency strings in a database safe way?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388922/how-to-process-price-currency-strings-in-a-database-safe-way)) ... are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

***Preface***

The next following answer takes this (currently closed) follow-up question by the OP into account ... [*"How to process price / currency strings in a database safe way?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388922/how-to-process-price-currency-strings-in-a-database-safe-way).

In order to work around the OP's ASCII-only limitation all currency symbols/characters got provided each in its unicode escaped form, but only when necessary.

***Approach / Solution***

In addition to the already provided solutions of the other thread there comes another possible implementation which uses a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance for a better lookup-performance where the currency-values do serve as (lookup) keys.

The parsing into a currency-part and a not yet fully validated number-part is based on a regex which partly makes use of the `Symbol`-category of [unicode escapes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) as well as of [named capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) and an [alternation](https://javascript.info/regexp-alternation) where the latter supports both cost-value variants which are ...

- either a leading currency-value and a trailing number-value
- or a leading number-value and a trailing currency-value.

The pattern is as follows ...

```regex
/^(?<currency_before>[A-Z]{3}|(?:(?:[A-Z]{2}\s*)?\p{S}))\s*(?<value_after>[\d.,]+)|(?<value_before>[\d.,]+)\s*(?<currency_after>[A-Z]{3}|(?:(?:[A-Z]{2}\s*)?\p{S}))$/u
```

... and gets [described at the related test-page](https://regex101.com/r/yPhxbp/3).

A former more strict pattern which does exclusively target the currency-symbol looks like this ...

```regex
/(?<symbol_before>\p{S})\s*(?<value_after>[\d.,]+)|(?<value_before>[\d.,]+)\s*(?<symbol_after>\p{S})/u
```

... and gets [described at its related test-page](https://regex101.com/r/yPhxbp/2).

The potential number-value is allowed to be formatted either by a comma as thousands-separator and an optional dot as decimal-marker or by a dot as thousands-separator and an optional comma as decimal-marker (e.g. the German way). This gets achieved by another capturing regex of following pattern ...

```regex
/^(?:(?<integer>\d+$)|(?<dot_surrogate>(\d+)?[.,]\d+$)|(?<thousands_dot>\d{1,3}\.(?:\d{3}[.,])+\d+$)|(?<thousands_comma>\d{1,3},(?:\d{3}[.,])+\d+$))/
```

... where the [description can be read at its related test-page](https://regex101.com/r/yPhxbp/1).

***Example Code***

```js
// - currency symbols provided in their escaped form when necessary.
const currencyToISOCodeLookup = new Map([
  // - map entries, each of following tuple:
  //   [<currencyKey>, <isoCodeValue>]
  ['\u20ac', 'EUR'], ['EUR', 'EUR'],
  ['\u00a3', 'GBP'], ['GBP', 'GBP'],
  ['$', 'USD'], ['US$', 'USD'], ['USD', 'USD'],
  ['HK$', 'HKD'], ['HKD', 'HKD'],
]);
// - original code ... same as above ... no escaping.
/*const currencyToISOCodeLookup = new Map([
  // - map entries, each of following tuple:
  //   [<currencyKey>, <isoCodeValue>]
  ['€', 'EUR'], ['EUR', 'EUR'],
  ['£', 'GBP'], ['GBP', 'GBP'],
  ['$', 'USD'], ['US$', 'USD'], ['USD', 'USD'],
  ['HK$', 'HKD'], ['HKD', 'HKD'],
]);*/
const regXCostPartials =
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/yPhxbp/3]
  /^(?<currency_before>[A-Z]{3}|(?:(?:[A-Z]{2}\s*)?\p{S}))\s*(?<value_after>[\d.,]+)|(?<value_before>[\d.,]+)\s*(?<currency_after>[A-Z]{3}|(?:(?:[A-Z]{2}\s*)?\p{S}))$/u;
const regXCostNumberFormats =
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/yPhxbp/1]
  /^(?:(?<integer>\d+$)|(?<dot_surrogate>(\d+)?[.,]\d+$)|(?<thousands_dot>\d{1,3}\.(?:\d{3}[.,])+\d+$)|(?<thousands_comma>\d{1,3},(?:\d{3}[.,])+\d+$))/;

function parseCostNumber(val) {
  const {

    integer,
    dot_surrogate,
    thousands_dot,
    thousands_comma,

  } = regXCostNumberFormats
    .exec(
      String(val).trim()
    )
    ?.groups ?? {};

  return Number(
    thousands_dot?.replace((/\./g), '').replace((/,/), '.') ||
    thousands_comma?.replace((/,/g), '') ||
    dot_surrogate?.replace((/,/), '.') ||
    integer
  );
}
function parseCostValue(val) {
  const {

    currency_before,
    currency_after,
    value_before,
    value_after,

  } = regXCostPartials
    .exec(
      String(val).trim()
    )
    ?.groups ?? {};

  const value = parseCostNumber(value_after || value_before);
  const code = currencyToISOCodeLookup
    .get(
      (currency_before || currency_after)?.replace((/\s+/), '')
    );

  // // here one could throw.
  // if (!code || Number.isNaN(value)) {
  //   throw new EvalError('Cost could not be parsed from "${ val }".');
  // }

  return (!code || Number.isNaN(value))
    ? null
    : { value, code };    
}

const costList = [
  '£.457,',       // - fails.
  '€ 2,000.0.0',  // - fails.

  'HK D 22',      // - fails.
  '22 HK D',      // - fails.
  '20EURO',       // - fails.
  '2 EURO',       // - fails.
  '€2,000.0.0',   // - fails.

  ' £ .20',       // - doesn't fail anymore from this point.
  ' £ .45 ',
  '£ .456 ',
  ' .457£ ',
  ' .9999 £',

  '0.001€',
  '0,02 €',

  ' EUR 2',
  ' EUR30 ',
  ' 421EUR',
  '635 EUR',

  ' €733,0000',
  '819.1200 €',

  ' US$21,000.00   ',
  'US $22,000.00   ',
  ' USD23,000.00   ',
  ' HK$ 24,000.00  ',
  ' HK $ 25,000.00 ',
  'HKD 26,000.00   ',

  '2.856,1124£',
  '3,700.999 £',
  '22,534.365£',

  '€ 6.342.567,40',
  '€ 8,263,157.22',
  '€74,522,927.33',
];
console.log(
  costList
    .map(parseCostValue)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```